# Starting React Native on Android Version 5.0

Tags: android, react-native, crash, crash-reports, crash-dumps

So I am running into an error on Android Version 5.0. It occurs when I build my react native instance manger like so:

```
    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(application)
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .addPackage(new CodePush(BuildConfig.CODEPUSH_KEY, application, BuildConfig.DEBUG))
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.BEFORE_RESUME)
            .setJSBundleFile(CodePush.getJSBundleFile())
            .build();
```

It's odd because I tested a production build on those phones, but they never had this issue before. The bug I am getting is this:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: something.something, PID: 10140
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{something.something/something.something.activity.SomeKindOfActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but DevSupportManagerImpl class was not found or could not be created
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but DevSupportManagerImpl class was not found or could not be created
 at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerFactory.create(DevSupportManagerFactory.java:79)
 at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.<init>(ReactInstanceManager.java:326)
 at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:227)
 at something.something.activity.SomeKindOfActivity.createReactInstanceManager(SomeKindOfActivity.java:356)
 at something.something.activity.SomeKindOfActivity.onCreate(SomeKindOfActivity.java:205)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6283)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
 at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerFactory.create(DevSupportManagerFactory.java:72)
 at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.<init>(ReactInstanceManager.java:326) 
 at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:227) 
 at something.something.activity.SomeKindOfActivity.createReactInstanceManager(SomeKindOfActivity.java:356) 
 at something.something.activity.SomeKindOfActivity.onCreate(SomeKindOfActivity.java:205) 
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6283) 
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder;
 at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevServerHelper.<init>(DevServerHelper.java:107)
 at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerImpl.<init>(DevSupportManagerImpl.java:190)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
 at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerFactory.create(DevSupportManagerFactory.java:72) 
 at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.<init>(ReactInstanceManager.java:326) 
 at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:227) 
 at something.something.activity.SomeKindOfActivity.createReactInstanceManager(SomeKindOfActivity.java:356) 
 at something.something.activity.SomeKindOfActivity.onCreate(SomeKindOfActivity.java:205) 
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6283) 
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/something.something-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/something.something-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/something.something-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/something.something-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/something.something-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/something.something-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/something.something-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/something.something-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/something.something-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/something.something-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/something.something-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/something.something-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/something.something-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
 at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevServerHelper.<init>(DevServerHelper.java:107) 
 at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerImpl.<init>(DevSupportManagerImpl.java:190) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
 at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerFactory.create(DevSupportManagerFactory.java:72) 
 at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.<init>(ReactInstanceManager.java:326) 
 at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:227) 
 at something.something.activity.SomeKindOfActivity.createReactInstanceManager(SomeKindOfActivity.java:356) 
 at something.something.activity.SomeKindOfActivity.onCreate(SomeKindOfActivity.java:205) 
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6283) 
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder
 at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.j
```

Comment: I have the same issue but only in Xperia phones